# Getting error There are no commands defined in the "module" namespace with nwidart

Tags: php, laravel-5

I'm trying to get started with nwidarts modular laravel architecture. I just got done installing it according to it's site: https://nwidart.com/laravel-modules/v2/basic-usage/creating-a-module

Now when I run the command `php artisan module:make <module-name>` I get the error:

```
[Symfony\Component\Console\Exception\CommandNotFoundException]
There are no commands defined in the "module" namespace.
```

I am running this in the root folder of my laravel app. So I am not entirely sure I installed it in the right place but there is an nwidart folder and stuff in my apps vendor folder so I guess I did it right? What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 3):

**follow the instructions on command**

```
step 1: composer require nwidart/laravel-modules

step 2: php artisan vendor:publish --provider="Nwidart\Modules\LaravelModulesServiceProvider"

step 3: insert in composer.json

   {
  "autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
      "App\\": "app/",
      "Modules\\": "Modules/"
    }
  }
}

step 4: composer dump-autoload
```

Answer (score 0):

If you've followed the installation steps for [nwidart/laravel-modules](https://nwidart.com/laravel-modules/v2/installation-and-setup) and still encountered the error, it means that the package is likely installed correctly. but there may be an issue with your Composer files.

I have resolved the issue by updating my composer file, using the `composer update` command to ensure dependencies are up to date and regenerate the lock file.

then it should recognize the module namespace and generate the module files correctly.